# ThreadPool. Avoid saturating the server

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

In a test application I pretend that a server only accepts a maximum number of connections simultaneously. For this I use a ThreadPool in the following way:

```
ThreadSocket client;
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
try {
    while (true) {
            client = new Client(serverSocket.accept());
            executor.execute(client);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
} finally {
    executor.shutdown();
}
}
```

The ThreadPool works perfectly but my question is what happens with the creation of thread type objects. The execute method expects to receive an instance already created but I understand that the creation of these instances can collaps the server.
Thank you.

Comment: Flyweight Pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Thread type objects are only created when you call `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);`. Then every new request will create `Client` objects, but they only need to impelment the Runnable interface - those are not new threads (this depends on your implementation, but hope the client doesn't create a new thread itself).

This might [help](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). You should also consider using `executor.submit` instead of `executor.execute`.